Writing rhythm/slash notation on a single line staff?
Slash and rhythm notation are common in jazz:

The use of the standard 5-line staff is perfect if you want to mix traditional and slash notation.  However, if there is no need to spell out notes, it seems that one line would suffice, even for guitar/bass/piano parts:

So, would you advise for or against it?  Has this been done before (maybe even commonly)?  (What about no lines at all?)
Personally I like the one-line version, it is tidier, there's no redundancy or clutter, and it clearly communicates the idea that no pitches will be involved.  OTOH, it may look unfamiliar and confuse people, especially when sight-reading.  What do you think?

No staff lines at all, just barlines and chord symbols, that's very commonly used, particularly hand-written. But a percussion staff with chord symbols, never seen that one. What purpose does the staff line serve? If you were to write that by hand, would you draw the lines with a ruler or buy single-line music sheets or something? Makes no sense.

What’s the context? If it’s for an ensemble that has more than 4 or 5 members that’s a bit of a different story than if it’s just a few people playing and singing.

Slash invented his own notation? I never knew Guns N' Roses was so musically well-rounded.

Please be aware that slash chord notation is way more generally used to denote a chord and its bass note, rather than the rhythm it's played in.

@ToddWilcox, the context is a small band (maybe up to 6 people) reading off the same chart (they'll have their own separate copies, of course).  I don't mean to break traditions for the sake of it but if you can improve things, why not.

Use five line staves for parts that aren't percussion
(I also know several percussionists who prefer five-line all the time)
The reason why I advise against one line is if you want your parts read, it helps to make them as readable as possible. The best readers read a lot and they have developed quick responses to what they read. They prefer to read what they are used to reading, which is what is most common. When they see something unusual, it usually gives them pause. It might be a very brief pause, but it's a little frustrating and confusing.
In other words, everything that piano, guitar, voice, trumpet, sax, clarinet, etc. readers read is always on a five-line staff. It is comfortable and reassuring to see your music on a five-line staff when you've become adept at reading. Even if there's a note at the top of the page that says "Yes, this is a one line staff but it's a guitar part", it still throws readers off to see only one line. There's constantly a part of your brain that is saying "something's not right, something's not right". Which is distracting and annoying when you're already paying attention to the part, intonation, dynamics, the groove, etc.
There's lots of other things players can read that's not your engraving, so why give them any reasons to avoid reading your work?
If you want your work read, make it as readable as possible

Does clef and key signature choice make any difference? I suppose the key is written in concert pitch, but then again I see fake books with C, Bb, etc. versions.

@MichaelCurtis - if the purpose of the line/s is just to show chords - as in for guitar or piano mainly, don't really see any point in having a key signature anyway.

@MichaelCurtis When I read properly done chord charts, I definitely read the key signature. If there’s no key signature but there are cadences that are like Fm - Bb7 - Eb, it’s gonna throw me off very slightly. Clef less so, but as a guitar player, if you hand me a part with single stave treble clef, I’m comforted to think you understand writing for guitar. If you hand me anything else, I’m worried.

It's going to depend on what else is going on for that particular part. If the guitar part has chords (as in the example) but then goes on to melody, then it makes sense to keep the standard stave, to save changing.
Personally, if it's purely chords, then no line at all will suffice - I use a bracket when there are two chords in a bar, but single bar chords written just as we write words - when one is finished, what's to do except stop that and play the next?. There's also a 'grille' with a diagonal slash that's pretty obvious.
I really expect seasoned players to be able to very quicky work out the raison d'etre behind the writing. Not too onerous, I believe.
Not involving percussion, as it's irrelevant to the question.

The question you should always ask with notation: Is a slightly cleaner/aesthetically more pleasing engraving worth breaking with what the musician knows, and thus risking confusion.
If you look at the options a musician would look at the first one and know what’s going on. With the others the first thought would be: Now what am I looking at?

Especially single line staves are dominantly used as rhythmic staves, so mainly for untuned percussion.
So doing this will cause confusion, and they do not really have any real benefit. Now, if we were to try to compress things a bit it could have some worth doing something like

especially when creating lists or collections of a lot of songs (not only because you save a line, but also you can save on line spacing.

I like the last offering. +1.  Wonder even if barlines are essential. There would be a time signature at the beginning, surely, and if the reader can't count up the the four shown, should they even be playing..?

@Tim That argument would make bar lines unnecessary in pretty much all conventional scores. The purpose of the barline is to allow for quick alignment and understanding of the measures. It allows the musicians to read and a whole bar or even more at once, rather than having to read and count everything individually. We could omit them, but they do offer a lot of value for essentially hardly taking up any space.

@Tim I HOPE that suggestion was merely mischievous!

@Laurence - what's mischievous..?

If I had chord symbols lined up with time signatures, I’d definitely prefer 4/4 over C. But then again I always prefer 4/4 over C.

Regarding the last version (| C /// | etc.), I've often seen the slashes written over the 'staff' directly above the chord indicating the number of beats the chord must last, omitted for chords lasting the entire measure or if two chords split the measure evenly.  Since these slashes can be much smaller, more like ticks, such notation does save space.  I think it is a commonly used convention but I don't know its name, anybody does?

@Ivan - the 'ticks' are there ostensibly to show how those chords are played - although many times, I've found them inappropriate. Sometimes better to simply write the chord concerned at the beginning, and leave the rhythm to the guitarist!
